# Regex for Commas without a space after them

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to make an expression that grabs all commas that do not have a space after them, and all colons.

I've tried `(,([^\s]))|([:])`, which is close, but also seems to grab the character after the comma that doesn't have a space.

I've also tried `(,\s+)|([:])`, which will grab all colons and all commas with a space after them as well as the space.

What I would like to be selected is enclosed in * * in the following:

> Hello, my name is*:* tibsar*,*okay?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got some examples of valid matches you are expecting ?

Comment: @noob updated the question!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this regex will do the work.

**Regex:** `(,(?=\S)|:)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\S)` This `positive lookahead` checks for character after `,` which is not a `whitespace` but **does not capture** it in match. `[^\s]` is same as `\S`.
- And used alteration `|` to match `:` which may appear anywhere.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/1)**

**[To match , at end of line(if needed).](https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/4)**

---

**Where you went wrong with [`(,([^\s]))|([:])`](https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/2) and [`(,\s+)|([:])`](https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/3)?**

- `(,([^\s]))` Does matches a comma followed by **non-whitespace** but it also **captures** it in the match.
- `(,\s+)` Straightaway matches a comma followed by a **whitespace**, so it's completely wrong.

Comment: Note that this won't work at the end of a string/line (because the end of the string is not a character, and thus won't match `\S`. You should probably use a *negative* lookahead instead: `,(?! )`. @tibsar: Do note that `\S` (and `\s`) are quite broad and cover a lot more than just spaces. Just in case the distinction between space and tab is important to you.

Comment: @Joey: Thanks for the suggestion. OP didn't specified the presence of `,` at the end so I didn't added `\n` to excluding part. But I did improved on it. [See improved one here](https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/4). If you have more suggestions you are welcome.