# Pandas read_csv not obeying a regex sep

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**Data**:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = '''ID,Level,QID,Text,ResponseID,responseText,date_key,last
375280046,S,D3M,Which is your favorite?,D5M0,option 1,2012-08-08 00:00:00,ynot
375280046,S,D3M,How often? (at home, at work, other),D3M0,Work,2010-03-31 00:00:00,okkk
375280046,M,A78,Do you prefer a, b, or c?,A78C,a,2010-03-31 00:00:00,abc
376918925,M,A78,Which ONE (select only one),A78E,Milk,2004-02-02 00:00:00,launch Wed., '''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r',(?!\s)')
```

**Problem**: I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786415/read-csv-with-extra-commas-and-no-quotechar-with-pandas). I ran into a new problem though. Notice at the end of the last line, it's a comma and a space. The regex in `sep=r',(?!\s)'` is supposed to ignore commas that are followed by a space.

**Question**: Is there a way to read the last column as literally `launch Wed.,` where the comma isn't a separator/delimiter but is literally a comma in the `last` column text - using `pd.read_csv` only?

**Error**:

```
ValueError: Expected 8 fields in line 5, saw 9. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

**Expected / desired output**:

```
          ID Level  QID                                  Text ResponseID  \
0  375280046     S  D3M               Which is your favorite?       D5M0   
1  375280046     S  D3M  How often? (at home, at work, other)       D3M0   
2  375280046     M  A78             Do you prefer a, b, or c?       A78C   
3  376918925     M  A78           Which ONE (select only one)       A78E   

  responseText             date_key           last  
0     option 1  2012-08-08 00:00:00           ynot  
1         Work  2010-03-31 00:00:00           okkk  
2            a  2010-03-31 00:00:00            abc  
3         Milk  2004-02-02 00:00:00  launch Wed.,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184634/regex-for-commas-without-a-space-after-them?answertab=active#tab-top).

Use this regular expression, `r',(?=\S)'` explained above.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = '''ID,Level,QID,Text,ResponseID,responseText,date_key,last
375280046,S,D3M,Which is your favorite?,D5M0,option 1,2012-08-08 00:00:00,ynot
375280046,S,D3M,How often? (at home, at work, other),D3M0,Work,2010-03-31 00:00:00,okkk
375280046,M,A78,Do you prefer a, b, or c?,A78C,a,2010-03-31 00:00:00,abc
376918925,M,A78,Which ONE (select only one),A78E,Milk,2004-02-02 00:00:00,launch Wed., '''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r',(?=\S)')
```

Output:

```
              ID                                 Level   QID      Text  \
375280046 S  D3M               Which is your favorite?  D5M0  option 1   
          S  D3M  How often? (at home, at work, other)  D3M0      Work   
          M  A78             Do you prefer a, b, or c?  A78C         a   
376918925 M  A78           Which ONE (select only one)  A78E      Milk   

                ResponseID  responseText  date_key          last  
375280046 S  2012-08-08 00             0         0          ynot  
          S  2010-03-31 00             0         0          okkk  
          M  2010-03-31 00             0         0           abc  
376918925 M  2004-02-02 00             0         0  launch Wed.,
```

Answer (score 2):

`read_csv` appears to be stripping the space from the end of the string prior to attempting to identify the separator. This can be worked around by modifying the regex to also check for commas identified as just prior to the end of the file:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r',(?!\s|\Z)', engine='python')
Out[347]: 
          ID Level  QID                                  Text ResponseID  \
0  375280046     S  D3M               Which is your favorite?       D5M0   
1  375280046     S  D3M  How often? (at home, at work, other)       D3M0   
2  375280046     M  A78             Do you prefer a, b, or c?       A78C   
3  376918925     M  A78           Which ONE (select only one)       A78E   

  responseText             date_key          last  
0     option 1  2012-08-08 00:00:00          ynot  
1         Work  2010-03-31 00:00:00          okkk  
2            a  2010-03-31 00:00:00           abc  
3         Milk  2004-02-02 00:00:00  launch Wed.,
```

Comment: Interesting! The documentation says: `Matches only at the end of the string`. I guess this means pandas reads line-by-line which is what allows `\Z` to work.

Comment: @Jarad I was only looking at this in the context of the above string when I wrote that, where it is the last character, but yeah, looks like it. `$` works just as well, and `\Z` works even when the problem line is not at the end (and the line still causes the problem when not at the end).