# Python Pandas read_csv with right Character Delimiter and right encoding way

Tags: pandas, csv, encoding, delimiter

Below is original csv file, there are different delimiter like " or ";" or ;
And it also includes Mandrin Chinese..

```
       "2IOUT_TOT_L1 Time";"2IOUT_TOT_L1 ValueY";"2IOUT_TOT_L2 Time";"2IOUT_TOT_L2 ValueY"
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:00;46145.625;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:00;44032.5
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:01;46125;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:01;44032.5
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:02;46125;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:02;44032.5
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:03;46125;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:03;44032.5
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:04;46156.875;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:04;44032.5
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:05;46156.875;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:05;44028.75
2019/7/31 上午 12:00:06;46156.875;2019/7/31 上午 12:00:06;44028.75
```

What I tried as below,

1. `df1=pd.read_csv('0731-0814.csv',sep=r';(?=\S)', engine='python',encoding='big5')`

it turned out->
UnicodeDecodeError: 'big5' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence

2. `df3 = pd.read_csv('0731-0814.csv', sep=r';(?=\S)', engine='python')`
   it turned out->
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MubQK.png)

Seems the delimiter choosen and the encoding way both aren't right.
What I  want it to be just like below,

```
2IOUT_TOT_L1 Time   2IOUT_TOT_L1 ValueY 2IOUT_TOT_L2 Time   2IOUT_TOT_L2 ValueY
0   2019/7/31 上午 12:00:00   46145.625   2019/7/31 上午 12:00:00   44032.5
1   2019/7/31 上午 12:00:01   46125.000   2019/7/31 上午 12:00:01   44032.5
```

Hope somebody could figure it out.
I will be grateful so much.

Comment: First read the file and convert delimiters to exact one delimiter. So you can read it using pandas

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to define separators as regex. Kindly refer to following posts as how to use them

1. [Pandas read_csv not obeying a regex sep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788493/10443817)
2. [Read csv file to Dataframe with custom delimiter](https://thispointer.com/pandas-read-csv-file-to-dataframe-with-custom-delimiter-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks for your information,but I still could not solve it. I have edited the question again. If you have other suggestion, I will very appreciate it.